Can I claim non-summer day camps as child care expenses on 2023 US taxes?
It is unclear to me if non-summer (e.g. Christmas or Thanksgiving) child care expenses can be claimed.  Logically I don't see why they would be different but I can't find any specific info saying either way.
For example in the link below the title says summer but the text makes no mention of this
https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-news/at-04-77.pdf
Neither do either of the below.

https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-news/at-04-47.pdf
https://www.irs.gov/publications/p503


Summer camp is brought as an example since it's one of the more common cases. However, seasons of the year is not a factor in qualifications.
See the IRS Publication 503:

You can count the cost of care provided outside your home if the care is for your dependent under age 13 or any other qualifying person who regularly spends at least 8 hours each day in your home.

and

The cost of sending your child to a day camp may be a work-related expense, even if the camp specializes in a particular activity, such as computers or soccer.

Overnight camps ran afoul of the first requirement, but day camps for the full day may be qualified.
When you say "Christmas or Thanksgiving", the question arises whether the camp is a work-related expense. I.e.: are you working while the child is in the camp. If you're sending your child during the holiday while you yourself are off then it's not work-related.
